# Is recovering SMTPPro configuration from a Magento installation that lost .modman directory possible?

Tags: extensions, smtp, modman

Recently it has come to my attention that the **.modman/** directory under Magento's *primary home* had gotten blown away.  I'm not sure when it happened, but the **.modman/** directory, in entirety, had disappeared from the Magento top level.  This was discovered while researching issues that seem to have arisen from *SMTPPro* having disappeared.  Doesn't seem like it's that far of a leap, being as digging through previous versions of the site show that the extension was living there (at least in part-- in the directory: **Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension**, under **.modman/**).

Obviously it came as no surprise that the *SMTPPro* extension sub-menu under the admin page had disappeared as well.  So my question is, how would one go about 're-registering' this extension (hopefully in a manner where previous configuration and settings would not be overwritten)?  I've tried the most simplistic attempt, namely, replacing the entire **.modman/** directory (salvaged from that previous version of the site stored in git) under Magento's home.  This did not work, and showed no promising signs.  IE there were still no admin page sub-menus for *SMTPPro*.

Does anybody have any advice for recovering this configuration, or any pointers to information that may be useful in this situation?  Anything you might be able to offer would be greatly appreciated, as I'm not really finding anything helpful via google regarding this issue.

Thanks for your time and help on this matter.

-Damon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is saved in the database under `core_config_data` so this part of your problem should be easy and not require any additional steps once the configuration pages are showing again.

Try the following:

1.) recover the .modman folder
 2.) run `modman repair`
 3.) refresh Magento's cache
 4.) log out and back into the back-end

(if recovering is not possible in step 1 you can simply reinstall it via modman clone)